# Custom People Picker is not showing results from SharePoint Group, where users are added using the SPD workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom people picker that fetches users from a SharePoint Group, only when the users are added manually from the Group settings.

If i add the users via SPD Workflow, the people picker is failing to read the data.

Deleted the Users and tried the Workflow, it didnt work. Removed app step from workflow and tried, still no use.

Reference to add User to SPD Group using Workflow: http://codelesssharepointinfopath.com/workflow-useful-rest-calls-add-user-to-group/

Expected: People Picker should show the users from the SPD Group

Actual: No Results found

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because it's a workflow (if you're using 2010 give 2013 a try). Do you get the same issue when you use Flow? If you don't get the same issue I think you need to force a refresh via the workflow. Worst case scenario you can use REST to add the user to the group through the workflow and I would imagine that would force a refresh.

Comment: Thanks @Zain. Im currently using REST to add users and the User Information list shows the Item created by as 'SharePoint App' in user Information List. We have not started using Flow.